# TYPO3 Override $GLOBALS[‘TYPO3_CONF_VARS’] in Site Configuration?

Tags: php, typo3, config

I want some of the `$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']` values (namely, those of the [Mail API](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/10.4/en-us/ApiOverview/Mail/Index.html)) to be site-specific. After reading [Configuration Overview](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/10.4/en-us/ApiOverview/Configuration/ConfigurationOverview.html), [Site Handling](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/10.4/en-us/ApiOverview/SiteHandling/Index.html), and [GLOBALS - TYPO3_CONF_VARS](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/10.4/en-us/ApiOverview/GlobalValues/Typo3ConfVars/Index.html), I'm still not sure how would it be an idiomatic way to do this.

Also, I'm using [helhum/typo3-config-handling](https://github.com/helhum/typo3-config-handling) for the TYPO3 configuration. The idea is basically having the same functionality that we have with the `contexts` (i.e having `prod.settings.yaml` and `dev.settings.yaml` load different values) but with sites, e.g. I want to have a different `$GLOBALS[‘TYPO3_CONF_VARS’]['MAIL']['defaultMailFromAddress']` value wether if I'm in one of my sites or another.

I actually don't know if this is possible to do. Maybe these are thought to be that, just global, and I have to come up with a more ad-hoc solution. E.g. changing the `$GLOBALS[‘TYPO3_CONF_VARS’]` array beforehand every time some process that accesses it.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: If it is only about `defaultMailFromAddress` I would suggest to simply set the From part of the mail each time you create one. Usually most extensions allow to set this via some configuration (Template) and `defaultMailFromAddress` is really only used as a fallback if the extension doesn't set a From correctly.

Comment: @MKlein Thanks a lot for the response. It's not actually just for `defaultMailFromAddress`, also for other MAIL values like `defaultMailFromName`, `transport_smtp_server`, and I guess that potentially others.

So you think this wouldn't make much sense to implement? That for the most part the `$GLOBAL['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']` are meant to be the same for all the sites?

Comment: I didn't think about this long enough yet, but for possible short-term solution you will probably need to do HTTP_HOST checks in AdditionalConfiguration and adjust the CONF_VARS there as needed.

Answer (score 1):

You can access Environment variables for domain specific configuration.
Or you use conditions in PHP.

Anyway you need to make your assignments in `typo3conf/AdditionalConfiguration.php` as all non constant values might get overwritten in `typo3conf/LocalConfigurathion.php`.

Comment: Thanks for answering!

But the thing is that I want to change `$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']` variables dynamically, namely some of the ones from 'MAIL' (e.g. `transport_smtp_server` or `transport_smtp_encrypt`).

Basically, depending on the Pid from which the email was sent (therefore a specific site), use different value for these variables. This values are stored as site config, which I can easily retrieve dynamically, with that Pid.

Comment: The thing is that for my TYPO3 setup, the same `AdditionalConfiguration.php` file will be loaded for every site, won't it?

My idea was to check the Email's Pid, get the Site from it, and then get the Mail site-specific config from it. Then modify the `$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['Mail']` array with that information. Is that possible? With Environment variables? But won't all the environment variables be the same for every site?

Comment: in the `AdditionalConfiguration.php` you can use programming logic while `LocalConfiguration.php` only can hold static values. A late evaluation might enable you to have different values in different context. environment variables can be set from Apache depending on the called domain. but you also can evaluate the called domain in your `AdditionalConfiguration.php` and set different values. (`$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']=='mydomain.tld'?'alternative 1':'alternative 2'`)